# How to retain previous code windows opening an existing visual studio 2010 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

When opening an existing solution in Visual Studio 2010 the code / classes previously working on no longer shows. Have to go to solution explorer and click each individual class again. This seemingly happened without making any changes to Visual Studio (odd.)

Is there an options setting that I am missing or any other solution to this event?

Comment: Do you have create/write permissions on the folder where the solution exists?

Comment: Yes I am able to add new classes to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your solution options (.suo) file has become corrupt -- delete tht, and it should then persist open windows from the next time you close Visual Studio.

Comment: The problem is tied to the one solution as other solutions open with code showing.

Comment: Not sure why but seems like after a few times deleting the .suo file for project it worked. Thanks Rowland.